how to call a dart function from js with dart:js_interop?
In flutter 3.22.0 i want to use WebAssembly compilation
I use 'dart:js_interop' to call a dart function from js
this is my code
updateStatus = (status) {
      if (status is int) {
        print(status)
      }
    };

@JS('status')
external set updateStatus(void Function(dynamic status) f);

and i got this error:
Error: External JS interop member contains an invalid type: 'void Function(dynamic)'.
external set updateStatus(void Function(dynamic status) f);


Can't you define it as external set updateStatus(JSFunction f);
Then you can assign a value to it like this:
updateStatus = (status) {
      if (status is int) {
        print(status)
      }
    }.toJS;

